# SignalR and sql dependency only on insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, signalr

I use signalR and SQL Dependency for real time notification in asp.net mvc 5.2
I implement `SignalR` from this link

```
http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/
```

no I have one problem , in this scenario on any change on table , SQL dependency run and return record,I want just on insert in table SQL dependency fired and return record,

because in this table I update a bit filed for read notification on user read notification in panel, when I update the filed SQL dependency fired,

how I can defined SQL dependency just for insert in table?

thank you for your help

i use this code

```
 public IEnumerable<Messages> GetAllMessages()
        {
            var messages = new List<Messages>();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Id],[Player_Id], [Message] FROM [dbo].[Notification] WHERE [Player_Id] = " + PlayerLogin.userId + " AND PlayerIsRed = 0", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        messages.Add(item: new Messages { Id = (int)reader["Id"], Message = (string)reader["Message"], Player_Id = (int)reader["Player_Id"] });
                    }
                }

            }
            return messages;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use your SqlDependency function something like that:-

```
     void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change && e.Info==SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)
                {
                    // your code
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly limit the type of data changes that SqlDependency notifies about. The filter suggested by Sunil will work, but there is another work around to only getting notified of inserts: triggers.

You could put an **insert trigger** on the table you want notified about, and have the trigger insert a record on *another* table, such as `PlayerNotification`, and then point your SqlDependency query to `PlayerNotification`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NotificationTrigger] ON [dbo].[Notification]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        [dbo].[PlayerNotification] ( 
              [Id], [Player_Id], [Message] )
    SELECT DISTINCT 
          [Id], [Player_Id], [Message]
    FROM 
        Inserted i
END
```

Comment: As far as I know signalR just send alert. Is there any way to get Id of the record added to database through signalR? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837459/returning-value-with-signalr-notification-when-actions-insert-update-delete